# PHP memcached extension not loading or being recognized on OSX

Tags: php, memcached, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having issues with loading Memcached on my machine(OSX 10.8.2 running MEMPstack(mac nginx mongo php)). I installed libmemcached, I pecl installed memcached, which created the memcached.so:

[image: Listing of contents of extension directory]

I then included the memcached.so extension in php.ini:

[image: showing extension inclusion]

After a little while of looking, it looked like the extension directory was wrong on phpinfo() so I moved memcached.so to the "correct one" and it's now showing up correctly in phpinfo():

[image]
[image]

I restarted php, restarted, restarted the memcached daemon. and I'm still getting:

***Fatal error**:  Class 'Memcached' not found in **/Users/noah/development/egood/api/lib/memcached.php** on line **2***

Any ideas? I'm loading everything 'correctly' as far as I know, but memcached is still not showing up.

Comment: What was the `extension_dir` set to before you changed it?

Comment: It was set to /opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in that I needed to create a memcached.ini file, and insert my memcached.so extension there.

Answer (score 1):

The extension you built was for (a third-party build of) PHP 5.4, and you're trying to install it to the extension directory for the Apple-provided PHP 5.3. Extensions are not compatible between PHP versions.

You need to figure out which version of PHP is actually active, rebuild the extension for that version if appropriate, and install the extension to the correct directory.

Comment: It's set to PHP Version 5.4.10. that's the current running version.